# What is the name of this Actionscript 3.0 Library?

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I remember recently coming across an Actionscript 3.0 library specifically made for events. You were able to write less code and easily define event listeners for your projects. I forgot the name and the link so if anyone has heard of such a library can you please link me to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [EventController](http://fla.as/ec/action.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to [AS3 Signals](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals). If you're not, you should check it out anyway as it is a great library.

Answer (score 0):

google - as3 events library.

the #1 search result is the answer you need.

Having a Q & A for this, is kind of silly. The top answer should be "Learn to use google".

Answer (score 0):

Also look at  [AS3 Common Event Bus](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-eventbus/index.html) . This event bus useful for our development.